# How can i get Gradle to run with javaFX and mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, gradle, javafx

For this project, I am trying to create a MongoDB application in Intellij with the addition of JavaFX for the database GUI. I am using java 15.0.1.

Please find the link to the program below:

https://connectglosac-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/s1905596_glos_ac_uk/Ehrd40zW4m9GjIlgmCnJrioBSm1t4RrnbGBm3Y_XRBKa0A?e=g6xvNR

I am running into issues when I try to run the Gradle program and receive the following error codes:

Exception in Application start

> method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
> method    at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) Caused by:
> com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating
> MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='dbuser',
> source='admin', password=, mechanismProperties=}  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:235)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:80)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:51)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:241)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:51)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:53)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:168)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:51)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:431)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:115)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:100)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:92)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:119)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:135)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:653)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:650)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:582)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:650)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:78)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:178)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.forEach(MongoIterableImpl.java:121)
> at
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.into(MongoIterableImpl.java:130)
> at
> com.accelita.repository.MongoRepository.getModules(MongoRepository.java:39)
> at
> com.accelita.universitydata.application.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:23)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
> ... 1 more Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command
> failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'bad auth : Authentication
> failed.' on server cluster0-shard-00-02.wdbc6.mongodb.net:27017. The
> full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "bad auth : Authentication
> failed.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}     at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:359)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:280)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:195)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:43)
> at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:69)
> ... 35 more Exception running application
> com.accelita.universitydata.application.MainApp

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: please format the stacktrace as code, and no external resources - provide a complete description here